# Wire Connection to Dryer Melted

Tags: electrical, dryer

I don't really know where to start to investigate why this issue happened. I'm going to try and test the voltage with a multi-meter later this evening to see if it's around 240 in total for the dryer.

But beyond that I could really use some guidance from this community on what else to try to determine the root cause.

The photo is all that I know at this point as it's from someone else's dryer connection that i'll help with to the degree that I can.

[image: Melted wire connection to dryer]

Comment: It probably is not a voltage problem.  More like loose and/or dirty connection.  That type of connection if loose/dirty will increase resistance(much more heat) and start melting plastic.  Check that the breaker is the right size for the dryer.  Should be 30 amps for common dryers.  A larger breaker plus a problem inside of the dryer would cause that also.

Comment: If you somehow had *significantly* more than 240V (up to 250V is considered "normal") then your ordinary 120V devices (lights, regular receptacles, most appliances except dryer, water heater, HVAC, oven) would all be getting at least 1/2 of that - e.g., if you had 300V on your dryer then you would have at least 150V for most other stuff and have **huge** problems. The problem is either the dryer itself, the plug, the receptacle or the breaker. Or a combination - because if the breaker is bad it wouldn't matter unless something else (dryer, plug, receptacle) went bad at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

From the lack of a cable clamp on that cable, I can tell that this dryer cord was installed by the consumer.

Science has shown that terminals screwed down without use of a torque wrench are far more likely to have an arcing failure from a poor connection.  That sure looks like one. It also shows humans are bad at guessing torques.

NEC 2014 adds 110.14 requiring use of torque wrenches/drivers on all connections which specify a torque,

It looks like a 4-wire dryer cord but I am not sure the neutral-ground connection strap was removed properly.  There should be high resistance between neutral on the plug and ground on the plug.  But that didn't cause this.

Answer (score 0):

When wires start acting as fuses, there's generally something wrong on the breaker side of things.

Oversized breaker, unsafe FPE/Zinsco breaker that won't actually trip on overload, etc.

There's probably also a fault in the dryer to make it pull that much current - though massive overheating *can* just be from loose connections arcing away at "normal" current levels.